# Android toolbar navigation icon and menu icon look different

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu, android-toolbar, android-icons

I'm developing app according material design guidelines. I am using toolbar, which is 56dp and icons for toolbar which are 48dp.

When i'm setting exactly the same icon as navigation icon and as menu item icon they look different.
[image]

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_toolbar_cross);
    }
```

and in menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_toolbar_cross"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

Why navigation button becomes bigger? 
Also I noticed that in Google IO 32dp buttons used for toolbar but according to material design specs they should be 48dp

Comment: Android has defined it in the way that menu item icon look little small than navigation icon. You cannot make any change in it